# Does each character focus on one super-power?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, shazam

In *Shazam!* (2019), Billy *shares* his powers with his siblings. It seems like each sibling gets a unique ability:

- Freddy - Flight
- Darla - Speed
- Pedro - Strength
- Mary - Unknown
- Eugene - Lightning

They all are strong and fast, but these traits were specific to each one during the film. Does this mean that they all have unique powers (so, for example, only Eugene will ever use lightning), or was this just the powers they were more attuned to, and could use almost by instinct?

Both theories make sense to me. On one, it's as if each power of SHAZAM gets divided by the siblings (possibly Mary inherits Solomon's wisdom, and they all share Atlas' toughness and Achilles' courage). On the other hand, Eugene (geeky hacker) got electric powers, Freddy (crippled) flew, Pedro (bulky and silent) got jacked, and Darla (youngest, probably not very confrontational) got speed.

Comment: I think that the theory and observations you have expressed in the post are on point correct. I cannot see _how anyone would answer_ that unless the movie creators themselves have talked about it. According to me **I stand with the point** that it surely seems like they have received **unique abilities**. Also it seems like you have really [dived deep in shazam](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shazam)

Comment: @RC0993 There may be creator comments I haven't found, or comic information I haven't read (and don't want to search for to avoid story spoilers). I'm hoping this will get answered, even if the answer is something like "We don't know" :P

Comment: There you go buddy !!! :D:D:D

Comment: I don't know how the next movie will deal with their powers, but according to wikipedia they all have the same powers as Billy, but Pedro, Eugene and Darla have added powers. Regarding the movie, I think it would be weird if they could use their full potential in the first try of their powers, since it took weeks for Billy to learn using them.

Comment: I smell captain planet :D

Comment: Any way to remove the spoilers from the question title?  This is the single most exciting and surprising moment in the whole movie, and I hate the thought of people having it spoiled.  (Note that I have no clue how to better state the title without losing the entire question)

Comment: @aryxus Maybe like this?

Comment: They derive powers from Greek Gods. One from each God.